# Phonegap 3.3.0 inappbrowser' s events are not firing

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I use phonegap to develop an app. This app works with some apis so, i have to use inappbrowser plugin. But after phonegap 2.9.x versions, the plugin's events are not firing. You can look at this problem on this forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/e5_5unC2fYs

. Apache has an announcement about it.[announcement](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2013/11/15/kitkat.html) But it is not a solve. Because, when i try to use phonegap with dreamweaver, i can choose phonegap 2.9 version in Dreamweaver Build service and Inappbrowser events work on Android 4.x devices. So, the problem is not about Android version. The problem is about Phonegap version. For some sdks(admob,...) i have to use eclipse. And i cant create a Phonegap 2.9 version app with command line. Do you have any idea about to choose version when creating app. Or change downgrade phonegap version.
Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested it myself, but if you're using phonegap build, you can try to include plugins in this format:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

, as well as the documented:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

see this [page](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/233) for plugin details

I had some trouble upgrading from 2.9.0 to 3.3.0, and it turns out I included my plugins in this format:

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

, which for some reason didn't work, when I used the  format my plugins started working again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my issue was not that the events weren't firing, but that there was a bug in my callback code (a `ReferenceError`).  Since this callback was the first callback to be run when the InAppBrowser received a "loadstart" event, all future callbacks did not run since the first callback raised an exception, making it seem like the InAppBrowser wasn't firing any callbacks at all.

The way I found this was actually by manually evaluating the callback in [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/).

```
cordova.require('cordova/exec').nativeCallback('InAppBrowser115751764',1,
  {
    "url" : "http:\/\/example.com\/path",
    "type" : "loadstart"
  }
,1)
```

I got the above snippet by reviewing the [verbose PhoneGap exec logs](http://codrspace.com/vote539/pro-tip-verbose-logging-in-phonegap-for-ios/).  You should also be able to find the callback ID by inspecting the `cordova.callbacks` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try install cordova:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

install plugin inappbrowser:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

now run:

```
phonegap run android
```